# how to pass golang map by value

Tags: go

```
AMap := make(map[int]int)
BMap := make(map[int]map[int]int)
var usersK []int
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    var k int
    fmt.Scan(&k)
    AMap[k]++
    BMap[i] = AMap
}
```

In this case all value in BMap is a same map. How to pass AMap by value not reference.

Comment: A map is a reference to the underlying structure. If you want to pass a copy of the map, you have to copy it element by element and pass that.

Comment: Passing a map by value is impossible, because a map isn't a value. It's a collection of values, which necessitates a reference.

Comment: @Flimzy "It's a collection of values, which necessitates a reference" --- this makes no sense. Everything is a value in Go.

Comment: @BurakSerdar "A map is a reference to the underlying structure" --- a map *is* a structure, not a reference to anything :shrug:

Comment: @zerkms, `unsafe.Sizeof(map[string]string{}) = 4`. Map is a pointer to a struct.

Comment: @BurakSerdar it's a not a reference though. And isn't its sizeof implementation-specific?

Comment: @BurakSerdar `unsafe.Sizeof([]string{}) = 12` `unsafe.Sizeof("foo") = 8`

Comment: @zerkms the point is that it is a pointer, at least in this implementation.

Comment: @BurakSerdar indeed, and a pointer != a reference. They have different semantics

Comment: @zerkms fine. A map is a pointer to a struct describing the map...

Comment: @zerkms a pointer is a reference. For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming) "A pointer references a location in memory," which seems like an accurate description to me. There's no need to split hairs here. "Pointer" is more *specific*, but "reference" is still *accurate*.

Comment: @Adrian "a pointer references to something" != "a pointer is a reference" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science) "a reference is often erroneously confused with a pointer or address, and is said to "point to" the data". Reference is an established term in a bunch of programming languages and the CS, I don't see why people deliberately swap the "pointer" and the "reference" terms, while they mean totally different concepts.

Comment: Skipping the sentence right before that clearly states that a reference is most commonly *literally a pointer* "Typically, for references to data stored in memory on a given system, a reference is implemented as the physical address of where the data is stored in memory" - the point being the distinction is just pedantry that doesn't help people understand the question or answers any better.

Comment: @Adrian "most commonly literally a pointer" --- how it's implemented does not matter for the userland: in the end of the day everything is just registers and cpu instructions. On the PL level a pointer and a reference are different concepts. "the distinction is just pedantry that doesn't help people understand the question or answers any better" --- it's the opposite. If the map **was** a reference this code would print a _non empty value_: https://play.golang.org/p/qxCJx5Tfv79

Comment: From [your own link, under Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)#Examples): "Pointers are the most primitive. Due to their intimate relationship with the underlying hardware, they are one of the most powerful and efficient types of references." Your example explains how references *might* work in *some* languages, **not** a fundamental quality of references.

Comment: @Adrian "not a fundamental quality of references" --- it's the very definition from the first line of a wikipedia page "a reference is a value that enables a program to indirectly access a particular datum, such as a variable's value or a record, in the computer's memory or in some other storage device."

Comment: Come on, `map` type is neither a pointer or a reference itself, it's an internal _structure_.

Comment: @zerkms OK now that's actively spreading false information. `map` in go is `*hmap` in the runtime, a *pointer to a structure*. See here https://dave.cheney.net/2018/05/29/how-the-go-runtime-implements-maps-efficiently-without-generics and here https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/map.go#L303

Comment: @Adrian it was discussed above already: being a pointer is a current _implementation details_, it's not backed up by the spec. Relying on an implementation specific things, not on a spec is a slippery slope.

Comment: @zerkms it doesn't matter. They can change the implementation details, but it behaves as a pointer today (because it is a pointer), which means the Go 1 Compatibility Promise says it must behave like a pointer going forward, regardless of the implementation.

Comment: I can agree it should behave _like a pointer_ in Go 1. But it's not a reference, because of https://play.golang.org/p/qxCJx5Tfv79 PS: sorry if I sounded like a jerk, I did not intend to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone map object to do it. However, I assume you won't really ;-).

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func Clone(a interface{}) interface{} {
    buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
    v := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(a))
    gob.NewEncoder(buff).Encode(a)
    gob.NewDecoder(buff).Decode(v.Interface())
    return v.Elem().Interface()
}

func main() {
    AMap := make(map[int]int)
    BMap := make(map[int]map[int]int)
    K := []int{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        k := K[i]
        AMap[k]++
        BMap[i] = Clone(AMap).(map[int]int)
    }
    fmt.Println(BMap)
}
```